# Error while Updating DB column plus one (column + 1)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'column_name + 1' for column 'column_name' at row 1

```
public function update($where,$values){
 
    $fields = array_keys($values);

    $query = 'UPDATE '.$this->table.' SET '.implode('=?,',$fields).'=? WHERE '.$where;
  
    $this->execute($query,array_values($values));

    return true;
  }


 $AutorDB = (new Database('tablename'))->update('id = '.$ID,[
            'column_name'  => 'column_name + 1'
          ]);
```

Setting direct the value it's working well (without the plus one +1 ):

```
$AutorDB = (new Database('tablename'))->update('id = '.$ID,[
            'column_name'  => 37
          ]);
```

I can't undestand why this column_name = column_name + 1 is not working. It's a problem with the array?

Comment: Parameter substitutions are treated as literal values, not expressions to be evaluated.

Comment: So you're trying to do `SET column_name = 'column_name + 1'`

Comment: Yes sir, I'm trying to do `SET column_name = column_name + 1`

Comment: `echo $query = 'UPDATE '.$this->table.' SET '.implode('=?,',$fields).'=? WHERE '.$where;` nobody but you knows what `$values` is.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. You can't do it with query parameters.

Comment: What I meant was that PDO is trying to do that, because that's how parameter replacement works. That's why it gets an error.

Comment: `'column_name + 1'` is a string and not an expression.  The `?` prepares/quotes it as a string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  so I should change my function to not use parameters (?) to calculate plus one? Right?

Comment: @Barmar so I should change my function to not use parameters (?) to calculate plus one? Right?

Comment: Or you could do a `SELECT` query to get the old value, add 1 in PHP, then use parameters to assign the new value.

Comment: You could define an `increment` method that takes a column name, and constructs the query with `SET $column = $column + 1`

Comment: BTW, you should use parameters in the `WHERE` clause, not just `SET`.

Comment: Thanks guys! this was my first question here and I appreciated the help. Cya.